# Sequential load of components in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In my angular code I have multiple components. I need to run some code, after last component will be loaded. How can I reach to this?
Here is a similar part of code:

```
var myApp = angular.module("reviewApp",[])

   .controller("MainController",function($scope){})
   .component("applicantDetails",{
       templateUrl : 'comp/Applicant_Details_Fields.html',
       controller : someFunction,
       bindings: {
        data: '=',
        formref: "<",
        index: "<"
    }
   })
    .component("investmetns",{                        
       templateUrl : 'comp/Investments_Fields.html',
       controller : someFunction,
       bindings: {
        data: '=',
        formref: "<",
        index: "<"
    }
   })
    .component("bankAccounts",{
       templateUrl : 'comp/Bank_Accounts_Fields.html',
       controller : callSomeFunction,
       bindings: {
        data: '=',
        formref: "<",
        index: "<"
    }
   });
```

**I need to load last component function "callSomeFunction" in the end**. Directives have priority, but for components it is not working, maybe any other alternative way to do this?

Comment: maybe you can do it with a `$postLink()`?

Comment: can you please provide a code part, as an example?How and where to write it which will load 'bankAccounts' component in the end?

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "It is not working" is not a problem description. It is difficult to write an adequate answer without a problem description.

Comment: If there are problems with data binding, be sure that code that depends on bindings are in the `$onInit` function. For more information, see [AngularJS Compile Service API Reference - Life-cycle hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks).

Comment: [EXPLORING ANGULAR 1.5: LIFECYCLE HOOKS](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2016/03/29/exploring-angular-1.5-lifecycle-hooks.html) is also a good read.

Comment: When I said It is not working, I meant that there is no **'priority'** property in the components. And I need that **last** component worked after all other components. My code is working correctly, I just need to add loading gif to my solution, and the function which must hide/show that loading gif must work after all components will be loaded. I need to know which component is loading in the and, after that I will call "Hide" function in that last components function.